# Damaged kernel which doesn't allow me to do anything

Tags: kernel, pop-os

Okay so i had asked a question yesterday about my pop os not recognizing any drivers. after a lot of searching i found that my kernel 6.2.6 is incomplete in installing. but right now it is running 6.2.6 as default or primary. in 6.2.6 kernel all package download is unsuccessful. I was able to load into previous kernel using the boot menu. when i press esc with logo it asks windows or pop os, but if i press esc right after 2-3 seconds it asks m old kernel or new kernel. so i was able to get into previous kernel which is working fine.

```
(base) madhusudan@pop-os:~$ uname -r
6.1.11-76060111-generic 

(base) madhusudan@pop-os:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image                                                
ii  linux-image-6.0.12-76060006-generic       6.0.12-76060006.202212290932~1674139725~22.04~ca93ccf    amd64   Linux kernel image for version 6.0.12 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                                            
ii  linux-image-6.1.11-76060111-generic       6.1.11-76060111.202302091138~1675975749~22.04~f771a7f    amd64   Linux kernel image for version 6.1.11 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                                             
iF  linux-image-6.2.6-76060206-generic        6.2.6-76060206.202303130630~1683753207~22.04~77c1465     amd64   Linux kernel image for version 6.2.6 on 64 bit x86 SMP                                                                
ii  linux-image-generic                       6.2.6.76060206.202303130630~1683753207~22.04~77c1465     amd64   Generic Linux kernel image
```

if i try to delete the old kernel it doesn't work

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pop-desktop : Depends: linux-system76 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

linux-system76 dependency is not met so i tried installing that

```
linux-system76 is already the newest version (6.2.6.76060206.202303130630~1683753207~22.04~77c1465).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-6.0.12-76060006 linux-headers-6.0.12-76060006-generic
  linux-image-6.0.12-76060006-generic linux-modules-6.0.12-76060006-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up linux-image-6.2.6-76060206-generic (6.2.6-76060206.202303130630~1683753207~22.04~77c1465) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.6-76060206-generic (6.2.6-76060206.202303130630~1683753207~22.04~77c1465) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.6-76060206-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.2.6-76060206-generic
kernelstub.Config    : INFO     Looking for configuration...
kernelstub.Drive     : ERROR    Could not find a block device for the a partition. This is a critical error and we cannot continue.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kernelstub/drive.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.esp_fs = self.get_part_dev(self.esp_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kernelstub/drive.py", line 94, in get_part_dev
    raise NoBlockDevError('Couldn\'t find the block device for %s' % path)
kernelstub.drive.NoBlockDevError: Couldn't find the block device for /boot/efi
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//zz-kernelstub exited with return code 174
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.6-76060206-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.6-76060206-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.2.6-76060206-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

it says could not find block device, im not sure what to do. because still now by default it loads the damaged kernel and it doesn't allow me to install anything even in older kernel

Comment: I solved it myself. Installed 6.2.6 kernel in old kernel, then at the final moment it was crashing bc it couldn't find efi partition. So then i went to emergency mode by causing an error. There i installed the downloaded package of new kernel and then fixed the error which i used to get into emergency mode. Then after rebooting it went into 6.2.6 kernel and everything works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I logged into old kernel using method mentioned in the question. And then i upgraded it. All necessary files were downloaded but they weren't installed because they couldn't find efi partition. so then i caused an error in /etc/fstab file which after rebooting takes me to emergency mode due to the error. Here i installed the downloaded package and it ran successfully. Then i solved the error which i used to get into emergency mode. Then i rebooted. 6.2.6 kernel was loaded and it is perfectly functioning now

also after that check for recoverable and corrupt files using

```
sudo sh -c 'fsck.vfat -n /dev/[partition name] || echo "RECOVERABLE errors found"'
```

if there are corrupt files run

```
sudo fsck.vfat -a /dev/[partition name]
```

Comment: make sure your /etc/fstab entry for the EFI partition works well now from your main system, or things will go wrong again in the future. Other than that: Congratulations!

Comment: yeah, i also checked for corrupted files and there were five which i was able to recover. also thanks for your help i was able to identify the problem and solve it